# Can I compare multiple computers using PowerShell? Specifically finding out which ones have a specific program and which ones dont

Tags: powershell

I need to compare multiple computers, finding out which ones have a specific program and which ones do not using PowerShell.

I am very new to this (about a week of PowerShell experience) so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remotely check whether software is installed or not:

```
# We need to check for both 64-bit and 32-bit software
$regPaths = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
  "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

# Get the name of all installed software registered in the registry with Office in the name
# (you can search for exact strings if you know them for specific versions)
$regPaths | Foreach-Object {
  ( Get-ItemProperty "${_}\*" DisplayName -EA SilentlyContinue ).DisplayName | Where-Object {
    $_ -match 'ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_NAME'
  }
}
```

How this works is it checks both the 32 and 64 bit registries for the installed software. Under the line `$_ -match 'ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_NAME'`, the `ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_NAME` should be replaced with whatever the software name is in "Add/Remove Programs". Note that this technique does not work with some programs that get installed via EXE based installers.

You can run this remotely on multiple computers as well using `Invoke-Command`:

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Path\To\File\With\Computer_Names.txt"
$results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
    # We need to check for both 64-bit and 32-bit software
    $regPaths = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
      "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

    # Get the name of all installed software registered in the registry with Office in the name
    # (you can search for exact strings if you know them for specific versions)
    $regPaths | Foreach-Object {
      ( Get-ItemProperty "${_}\*" DisplayName -EA SilentlyContinue ).DisplayName | Where-Object {
        $_ -match 'ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_NAME'
      }
    }
}
```

`Invoke-Command` can run the embedded `ScriptBlock` on many computers at once. When all computers in the list have run the command, you can check the result per computer (it returns as an array so you can check the `PSCOMPUTERNAME` Property on each `$result` to see which computers don't have the software. The way the code above works, it should return an object on the computers that have it, and nothing on the computers that don't.

Comment: "C:\Path\To\File\With\Computer_Names.txt" - Do I need to first retrieve all of the computer names and then output it to a file for this to work?

Comment: You don't have to retrieve an array of computer names from a file, it's just one example of how you might read in an array of computer names from some source. You could also get the computer names from Active Directory as well if you run the script from a system with RSAT tools installed.

Comment: I received this error message when attempting to run the script. Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.
At line:2 char:12
+ $results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Comment: Without seeing your input file it's tough to know what's wrong, but if you're reading in the computer names in from a file, it should be one FQDN per line. You should still also check the `$results` object, because it might just be blowing up on one or more badly-formed computer names in the array as well, but succeeding for the well-formed ones.